# Comparing by Year using Yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to make a query comparing only the year, I want to get all the posts on any given year

```
$posts = TPost::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('YEAR(date)'=>$year),array('order' => 'date desc', 'limit' => 4));
```

I typed in the year function in the query and Yii is giving this error

```
t_post" does not have a column named "YEAR(date)".
```

which is fine because , but how do I use the Year mysql function in the query using Yii?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what format you save the date in MySQL, so just Google over: [mysql fetch year from date](https://www.google.lv/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql%20fetch%20year%20from%20date&oq=mysql%20fetch%20yyear&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.7603j0j7)

Eventually in your yii request you need to use **findAllBySQL()** (rather than findAllByAttributes() ).

```
$posts = TPost::model()->findAllBySQL("SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE <MySQL expression to fetch year only> = '{$year}' ".
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the findAllBySQL function.